# Why I'm not able to round a column in dataframe pandas

Tags: python, database, pandas, rounding

I'm trying to round to round a column in my dataframe. The problem is that I'm getting the numbers sorted but with decimals.

I've tried different options:

- `df['DataFrame column'].apply(np.ceil)`
- `df['DataFrame column'].round(decimals=number of decimal places needed)`

Example of my code:

```
df = df.sort_values(by = ['SCORE'], ascending = False)

df['SCORE'].apply(np.ceil)
```

df

Expected result in columns 'SCORE' should be for example from `100.000000` to `100`, `96.199205` to `96` or `95.983358` to `96`.

Comment: add `.astype(int)` at the end maybe?

Comment: Was about to answer with that :D
``df.sort_values(by='SCORE', ascending = False).apply(np.ceil).astype(int)`

Comment: Check for `nan` and non-float/int in the column? That might create a problem for `np.ceil`.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`np.round()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.round_.html) and [`astype()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html)

**Ex.**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'SCORE':[100.000000,96.199205,np.nan,95.983358]})
print(df)
"""
   1. if series has NaN value, solution work for pandas 0.24+
      df['SCORE'] = np.round(df.SCORE).astype('Int64')
   https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html

  2. If series has not NaN value, try this
    df['SCORE'] = np.round(df.SCORE).astype(int)

"""
df['SCORE'] = np.round(df.SCORE).astype('Int64')
print(df)
```

**O/P:**

Before

```
        SCORE
0  100.000000
1   96.199205
2         NaN
3   95.983358
```

After

```
     SCORE
0    100
1     96
2    NaN
3     96
```

Comment: This truncates, does it not?

Comment: `np.round` is vectorised and would be better than apply invocations

Comment: You can apply `np.round` to the whole series: `np.round(df['SCORE'])` instead of applying it.

Comment: @ifly6 we need to check if series contains `NaN` value or not, otherwise, it will raise an exception if series has `NaN` values

Comment: You can't have an `int` series with `nan` in it

Comment: @ifly6 You're right, it also accepts where series contains `NaN` or not, `np.round(df['SCORE'])` will return round value.

Comment: But your output isn't of type `int`. This chap seems to want his data as type `int`

Comment: Thanks for your help guys! I'm checking answer and I think it's working :)

Answer (score 1):

```
df["SCORE"] = df['SCORE'].round().astype(int)
```

If you, pass a number to `Series.round`, like `round(2)`, it will give you the series with two decimal places.

- `round()` gives the result in float but not in integer
- `astype()` converts the float to int

Comment: thanks! It works perfectly! just what I was looking for :>)